# Java ConcurrentHashmap issues

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I'm facing a weird behaviour of a ConcurrentHashmap when putting my values (with potentially some hash conflicts on the keys, but I understood that this is well managed by Maps as they store same hash values in linkedlists).

```
ShowdownFreqCountVO previousValue = totalCountsShowdown.put(currentKey, new ShowdownFreqCountVO(0, 0));
```

For some particular value, this line will overwrite an existing value while I am sure that it is not yet in the map as

```
totalCountsShowdown.contains(currentKey)
```

will return false when called right before the put.

After the "put" instruction, the map's size will remain identical and the previousValue will contain indeed a value stored previously but under a different key.

Any idea on what I could be doing wrongly?
(note: at this stage, I'm not yet multi-threading, so this can't be the problem)

Many thanks for any hint !
Thomas

PS: hash function on the key (which contains only an array of byte values) is the following:

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(values);
    return result;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ShowdownFreqKeysVO other = (ShowdownFreqKeysVO) obj;
    if (!Arrays.equals(values, other.values))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the keys are modified after they're stored in the Map. Never do that. And preferrable use an immutable class as your key, to avoid such bugs.

Comment: Two things: try running `contains(currentKey)` twice in succession to see if the contains() method is somehow modifying your map. And secondly, what is the purpose of your `result` variable (other than storing the result) in your `hashCode()` method? Right now its multiplying 31 by 1 (which is just 31) **then** adding the hashcode of the values array. Did you mean: `result = prime * (result + Arrays.hashCode(values));`?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but you seem to be surprised that a Map can hold the same value twice. Why? It's the keys that are unique, not the values.

Comment: @EJP If I read it correctly, OP is describing "weird" behavior where a put operation with a specific key overwrites value of another key (and returns the corresponding object) even when a `containsKey()` call was made right before the `put()` and returned **false** (essentially proving OP's equals() and hashCode() method to be sound [or at least, able to differentiate between keys]).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JB Nizet !
Problem was indeed that the keys were referenced and modified after storing in the map.